# Query on python control flow statements and lambda exp

Tags: python

In python, We say everything is an object,

for instance: expression `x<y` internally calls `x.__lt__(y)`

where `__lt__` is the method in object  of class('int' say if values are 2 & 3) and x and y are reference variables to objects

and

User defined Function `square(3)` internally calls `square.__call__(3`)
where 'square' is the name of an object of class 'function' and reference variable 'square' points to that object name 'square'.

So,

How are if-elif-else, for, break, continue, pass, lambda statements interpreted internally? as objects?

If yes, Can you give some examples to visualise in similar above manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statements are not represented as objects in Python (including the examples you give).  Rather, the way things work is that language syntax often maps to "hooks" that you can define to influence what the syntax does in a particular situation.  For instance, the `<` syntax maps to the `__lt__` hook.  It doesn't mean that the `<` symbol "is an object"; it just means that you can define methods on your objects to customize how they work with that syntax.

Some of the syntax you ask about can be influenced in a similar way via magic methods.

`if` checks whether its condition is boolean true.  That is, `if x:` internally calls `bool(x)` to determine whether `x` "counts" as True or False.  You can influence this decision by defining a `__nonzero__` method (or `__bool__` in Python 3).  `elif` works the same way.  (You cannot change what `else` does.)  Also, of course, a lot of `if` conditions involve comparisons, and you can customize those comparisons in the way you already mentioned.  For instance, if you want to customize how `if myObject < 2` will work, you can write a `__lt__` magic method.

`for` engages the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).  You can make your own objects iterable by defining the `__iter__` and/or `next` methods.  You can't influence `break` and `continue` exactly, but you can write iterators that "fake" continues by skipping elements, or "fake" breaks by raising `StopIteration`.

`lambda` is just another syntax for defining a function.  You can't change what `lambda` does, and it's not clear what the point would be anyway.

`pass` is a do-nothing statement.  You can't change what it does, and there really would be no point: it exists specifically to do nothing.

Comment: BrenBarn i have written my question wrongly, i edited now. am yet to read you answer ):

Comment: Bren Can you edit your answer--- 'but neither are the examples you mention. Rather, the way things work in Python is that language syntax often maps to "hooks" that you can define ' --- this does not look fine to me after i edited my question, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Sham: I don't see that your edit changed the substance of your question.  Are you saying my answer is incorrect or doesn't answer the question?  I don't understand what you're saying in your comment.

Comment: Bren Am saying that you answered my question, but your comment on mistakes in my question about < as object will confuse in future reference, i later edited this question for the same.

Comment: Bren For your statement: "if checks whether its condition is boolean true. That is, if x: internally calls bool(x)" --- i would like to know, which object's bool() method is called?

Comment: @Sham: `x`, as it says in the answer.  That is, if you actually write `if x:`, where the only condition is a single object, then `bool` is called on that object.

Comment: Bren for yourstatement: "You can influence this decision by defining a __nonzero__ method (or __bool__ in Python 3). " --- I did not get you, any example?

Comment: Can somebody help me understand on my previous update?